# Nuget requires Paketsource assignment on almost every package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I'm not sure when it started but my Nuget packge manager in Visual Studio now doesn't recognize packages until I manually given it their Sourcename. This is very annoying and other users i asked personally do not even have the option to change their package source tight from the installtion tool.

My window looks like this right now:
[image: nuget_screenshot]

just to clarify, because the picture is in german, the part behind the red x is my problem it says: Requires Packagesource assignment.

I already tried to reinstall my Visual Studio, this didn´t work.

So Probably there is some residual userdata file with saves my config of VS, but before a start scraping my whole filesystem I wanted to try it here.

So if anyone knows how to get rid of the requirement, it would be great.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the nuget source in your vs?